# insert values from one table into another table with different design in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm back with another (possibly) silly question. sorry.

I have a pretty complicated query which joins 4 tables and computes the sum of a column based on the other two columns in two tables. the result returned is like this:

[Image http://eternalvinay.iocleicester.com/blahblah.png](http://eternalvinay.iocleicester.com/blahblah.png)

Now, I want the results to be like the right hand side of the image. the number rows per month/year **might** change though its 4 for now.

I am creating  a temporary table as:
    Declare @TmpTable (id int identity, AnsSum float, AnsMonth int, AnsYear int)
to store the values from image --> table1. However, I cant figure out how to convert those rows into the format required by table 2.

So, Any hints on this please?
Thanks so much..

ps: I tried to google and related questions here, no luck.
pss: I am not expecting the exact answer too, i am quite interested to learn new things so if you know where i can learn to do this, a push in the right direction, that would be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use cross apply to get all the values in a comma delimted format in a single column. instead of "4" different columns.  The problem is this "4" cannot be defined everytime. it may increase or decrease and it is not advisable to have this as columns.

SELECT DISTINCT AnaMonth, anayear, [DerivedColumn] FROM @TmpTable A
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT AnaSum + ',' FROM @TmpTable B 
WHERE A.AnaMonth = B.AnaMonth 
AND A.AnaYear = B.AnaYear 
FOR XML PATH('') 
) AS C (DerivedColumn)

You will get [6.0000, 1.000, 8.0000, 5.0000] in one column for month 5 and year 2010 etc ... You could use this as a table to query for any particular month.

Hope this helps

Comment: Aweeesome! this worked like a charm!! you are a genius!

thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

So you have normalized data and you want to pivot the result set to create [repeating groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups).

You could use [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) but you'd need some other attribute in your base table to define the four columns.

I would recommend *do not* pivot this query in SQL.  Just do the query against the database and get four rows per month/year.  Then write code in your application to aggregate the results by month/year.

Comment: Hmm! interesting, I am looking at the PIVOT right now, it looks like it can do the job, but I am curious why you suggest to use the programming language for this?  
  
also, the results in the table are already aggregated. so I dont need to use aggregate again, just transform them rows with distinct month/year into columns!

Comment: Pivot cannot do the job because you don't have an attribute in your base table to determine the columns of the pivot.  In other words, how can you define the pivot for which row goes into each respective column?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, looks like I had misunderstood the pivot!